# How to draw an image next to mouse cursor ANYWHERE on the screen?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, mouseevent, pinvoke

My code is in C#, I already have code that gets me the coordinates by using the GetCursorPos() function of Winapi, now I wish to draw an image (bmp and png as well) next to the cursor.

I need this to work on any window/program/desktop etc'.. anywhere on the screen at anytime. that is why I am dealing with Winapi and not .net which will limit my result to my form's perimeter only. and as I said I need it to work anywhere.

What is the most simple and direct way to accomplish this? I have searched and searched for the way to do this but didn't find anything conclusive. I'll appreciate any help..

Comment: _"What is the most simple and direct way to accomplish this"_ - use a marker pen on the monitor.  Seriously, look into [GetDC(NULL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a DC for the entire screen. Then you can draw essentially anywhere

Comment: @Micky Thanks for the answer, my note was because I saw some people using 3rd party libraries and such and I was looking for the direct way. I didn't know about GetDC(NULL) and this was what I was looking for.

Comment: You are quite welcome good sir.  Good luck in your travels :)

Comment: Use a transparent window and move it around to follow the mouse, rather than trashing the display.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for the great idea, I wrote some code.. now my problem is GetCursorPos() only gets me the point location while on the form itsealf and not anywhere on windows, so I guess it's because I am using WindowProc to intercept WM_LBUTTONDOWN (which i'll also need eventually) how could I get the cursor position even if it's not on my form? Thank you.

Comment: If you don't know the answer to that question, you have little hope of success. What you are attempting requires deep knowledge of Win32 which you don't have. You should face up to this and try to fill these gaps. Start by reading about client and screen coordinate systems.

Comment: `I need this to work .. anywhere on the screen at anytime`. Just a nitpick, but I guess/hope the latter part actually means `at anytime that the form has the input focus`. That deserves to be stated explicitly.

Comment: @dxiv That is actually _not_ what I meant. I needed to make the mouse cursor look different (not changing the cursor itself) on any program. to conclude, whenever the user sees the mouse no matter which application is focused at the time.

Comment: Assuming you got it to work, what would happen if you ran two instances of your program at the same time, set to "embelish" the mouse cursor with different images? May be just me, but I'd find it between annoying and downright rude if a program decided to arbitrarily take over the mouse cursor `anywhere on the screen at anytime`. I am not saying it's impossible. But it's not trivial, and purposely not so.

Comment: @dxiv I am doing it for my own sake only, I will be the only user of the program and it's intended for annotations. I want to put an image of a clicked mouse when it's clicked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I am starting to think it's a lot of time learning and developing to accomplish what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a transparent window covering the whole screen and get the mouse movements in its WindowProc (and not the WindowProc of your Form).

If thet's not feasible, call [SetCapture()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262(v=vs.85).aspx) for your Form Window when you go into this mode and [ReleaseCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) when you exit this mode.

As @JonathanPotter mentioned, drawing to your own transparent window is a lot better than drawing with `GetDC(NULL)`.